# designing a database for cms

Tags: database-design

what are the first steps for designing a database system for cms? can u please help me with it? i dont know how to start it. what should i do for the begining?

Comment: Requirements, requirements, requirements.

Comment: @Otávio - But .. that's not the agile way ..

Comment: @Jaimal - even in Agile you have to start somewhere, stories, use case, whatever. Being agile does not relieve you from knowing what you want to build.

Comment: @Jaimal - I know, sometimes Agile is taken as a license to blindly hack at things and that irks me. I am very much for iteractive development but I've seen my share of projects that don't have a clear mission and the first iteration is when you get it installed at the client and they refuse to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Gather requirements. Write them down in plain English (or whatever human language you prefer). Be sure you have a clear understanding and definition of every item and action you write down.

Then identify data entities, relations between them, and processes that modify them.

Data entities become tables (with each row representing one instance). Data relations become foreign keys. Processes become methods or functions in the application that uses the database, although you might want to implement a part of the functionality in stored procedures to minimize the amount of data that goes into and out of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to download one of the FOSS CMSes out there, install it locally and analyze the database structure. I'm sure there are plenty of solutions out there, I'd use [Drupal](http://drupal.org) or [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org). These two will give you nice ideas.